# PHPMailer 5.2.0 sends out 2 mails each time

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, phpmailer

First of all; sorry if this has been asnwered before, I have searched for the last couple of days with no luck.

I am using PHPMailer 5.2.0 to send a mail from a form, which is called by an AJAX call from a jQuery script with [jQuery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), each time I send the mail it sends it out twice. It must be that the script is called twice but I can't figure out where it happens.

Here is the php script:

```
<?php
require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$navn= $_REQUEST['navn'];
$tlf= $_REQUEST['tlf'];
$ring= isset($_REQUEST['ring']) ? $_REQUEST['ring'] : 0;
if($ring == 0)
{
$ring2 = " - og vil gerne ringes tilbage.";
}
else
{
$ring = "";
}
$email= $_REQUEST['email'];
$sendToOwn= isset($_REQUEST['sendToOwn']) ? $_REQUEST['sendToOwn'] : 0;
$besked= $_REQUEST['besked'];

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

//$body             = "testing 30/11";//file_get_contents('contents.html');
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "SMTP.Server.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                       // 1 = errors and messages
                                       // 2 = messages only

$mail->SetFrom('noreply@sentfromDomain.dk', 'Name');

$mail->ClearReplyTos("");
$mail->AddReplyTo("mail@adress.com","Name");

$mail->Subject = "Besked fra mjtransportogflyt.dk";
$mail->MsgHTML("TEST FOR HELVEDE");//"<p>Denne mail er sendt af ".$navn." (".$email.") - ".$tlf.$ring2."</p><p>".$besked."</p>");
$mail->AltBody = "Denne mail er sendt af ".$navn." (".$email.") - ".$tlf.$ring2."<br /> ".$besked; // optional, comment out and test

//$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "Sendto@thisadress.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Kasper John Doe");

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function validate(formData, jqForm, options) { 
        for (var i=0; i < formData.length; i++) { 
            if (!formData[i].value) { 
                $('#results').removeClass('info').addClass('error');
                $('#results').html('<p><strong>Udfyld venligst alle felter</strong></p><p>Din besked blev <strong>ikke</strong> sendt</p>'); 
                //Test om det bliver kaldt
                //alert('works?');
                return false; 
            } 
        }
        var options = {
            //target: '#results',
            success: showResponse
        };
        function showResponse(statusText){
            $('#results').removeClass('info').addClass('success');
            $('#results').html('<strong><p>Beskeden er sendt!</p></strong>');
            //Får tilbagemelding fra processed.php
            //alert(statusText);
        }
            $('#myform').ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    $('#myform').ajaxForm({beforeSubmit:validate})

});
```

And last heres the form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="processed.php">
    Lots and lots of inputs and stuff
    <!--submit button below-->
    <button class="btn action">Send besked</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can inspect with a client tool (firebug, chrome developer tools, opera dragonfly etc.) network tab and see if it sends out two requests or not. This way you can identify if it's a jQuery problem or PHP problem.

Comment: I have not been able to find any tracks of it. But then again I wouldn't know where to look so I have just been looking in random places, I would appreciate it if you could tell me where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your issue is that you are adding the `ajaxForm` to the form which by itself will automatically send the form. However, before it sends, you are sending it to the `validate` function which validates it, and then you are submitting the form in there also by using `ajaxSubmit`.

Remove the `ajaxSubmit` and that should fix it as the `ajaxForm` will submit it itself

I think this will work

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        beforeSubmit:  validate,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 

    }; 

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 



function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){
    $('#results').removeClass('info').addClass('success');
    $('#results').html('<strong><p>Beskeden er sendt!</p></strong>');
    //Får tilbagemelding fra processed.php
    //alert(statusText);
}

function validate(formData, jqForm, options) { 
        for (var i=0; i < formData.length; i++) { 
            if (!formData[i].value) { 
                $('#results').removeClass('info').addClass('error');
                $('#results').html('<p><strong>Udfyld venligst alle felter</strong></p><p>Din besked blev <strong>ikke</strong> sendt</p>'); 
                //Test om det bliver kaldt
                //alert('works?');
                return false; 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, now it only sends 1 mail, although goes straight to processed.php now instead of firing showResponse. Any idea?

Comment: Did any javascript error appear? I have edited my answer a bit to more copy the example from the developers website. Try the above and see what happens?

Comment: It still doesnt fire the functions I'm afraid. Have a look here http://mjtransport.dk/index2.htm The form is on the page called 'kontakt'

Comment: No it still doesn't work - I'm about to pull my hair out - http://mjtransportogflyt.dk/index.htm

Comment: You have a syntax error in your javascript. You need a closing `}` on your validate function. Once you have done that, it should work.

Comment: I must be blind, I cannot for the life of me see where it should go. There are 3 opening backets and 3 closing ones in the validate function. Can you check it again if you have the time? I might have screwed up with the link above. It should be the correct version now. I have put up the function on a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Travii/tGKED/

Comment: What you posed at jsFiddle, and what you have on your website are two different versions. You have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CGSz6/) when you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CGSz6/1/). Notice the extra bracket on the validate function. I copied this straight from your website here (http://mjtransportogflyt.dk/index.htm)

Comment: Oh dear, I am gonna clean up the code and files when I get a chance.
Anyway, I got the correct version online now and the validate function works, but the showResponse one does not?

Comment: The problem is, that with your validate function, you are actually only checking the form elements that have text in them, so it will (I think) ALWAYS return true. If you go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/leereichardt/UkWtF/) I have given you code you should just be able to copy and paste. To make it work, what you should do, is give any input the class `required`. The validate function will them loop through the elements in your form and search for the inputs that are required (via the required class) and check that they are not empty. If they are empty, it will return false, else return true

Comment: This is beautiful! 
Thanks a lot - You've saved the day.